# Jest Throw Error: TypeError: node.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: jestjs

When the DOM API used in `node_modules`, it will throw this error.

How can I fix it?

```js
node.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', transitionEndHandler_1);
node.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionEndHandler_1);
```

When I use Jest to test my transition, i will call `addEventListener`, but it will throw an error in Node.js.

Comment: these code is in `node_modules`, how to use DOM API to avoid error?

Comment: Could you provide error detail?